# Arc vs Arc Measure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, intuition

> Theorem: The radius of a circle is perpendicular to the tangent at the point of tangency

One particular proof I came across is as follows:

[image] $$\text{The measure of} \: \: \angle CAB \: \: \text{is one half the arc it cuts off. Since the chord is the diameter, the arc is half the circle, so } \angle CAB = \frac{180^{\circ}}{2}$$

However here $180^{\circ}$ is not the length of the arc. It is the measure of the angle that subtends it.

Similarly stated:

> The measure of an inscribed angle is half the arc it subtends

[image] It is stated that $\angle ABC = \frac{\frown {AC} }{2}$

But shouldn't it be $2r\angle ABC = \frown AC \implies \angle ABC = \frac{\frown AC}{2r}$

Answer (score 1):

Those quotes are misleading, they make one think that an arc is measured by arc length. But that's not what's going on in this context. Adding a few words to those quotes might clear things up:

- The *angle* measure of an inscribed angle is half the *angle* measure of the arc it subtends.

You must take care, of course, that these angles measures use the same units: you could use units of degrees; or instead use units of radians.

So, for instance, the angle measure in degrees of a semicircular arc is indeed $180^\circ$, which equals half the angle measure in degrees of the whole circle which is $360^\circ$. And so $\angle CAB$ does indeed have an angle measure in degrees equal to $\frac{180^\circ}{2} = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

An *arc* is a piece of a curve in the euclidean plane. The *measure* of this arc is its length. If the arc is a piece of a circle then the length of the arc, divided by the radius of the circle, is the natural measure for the *angle* subtended at the center of the circle.

In your figures it is tacitly assumed that the drawn circle has radius $1$. – By the way: There must be  proofs of said theorem that rely on more basic facts about circles and tangency.